# The case of a piece that could go missing

Tags: real, reverse-puzzling

What piece of hardware was after all unnecessary?  And how?

[image: plus sign and images laid out somewhat like long addition]

<sub>These diagrams, though somewhat schematic, are meant to directly
represent everything pertinent.
Nothing has been omitted or added to confound or mislead.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The right half of the assembly on the middle row

because

> the combined assembly on the bottom row replaces that part with the assembly from the top row.
>  [image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the

> choke valve shown in the second row.

This is because

> you could turn handle of the switch valve shown on the top row clockwise, choking off the inflow to the junction. The flow will mostly shoot over the lower branch, and any drips that go down the lower branch anyway will be held by the flap covering the lower outlet.

Comment: I wish two check marks could be assigned.  Seems that you have solved the same puzzle in real life.  Indeed there are drips!  (Signed, a drip.)